# Extract values from Specific Structured Object Array in ES6/ES7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

Let me explain my problem.

I have data like :

```
data: {
  carType:  {key: 'sport',     label: 'Sports Car'},
  carStyle: {key: 'striped',   label: 'Striped (with blabla)'},
  carPrice: {key: 'expensive', label: 'Above 500.000$'},
  carOptions: [
    {key: 'aluminium',   label: 'Chrome Wheel (Available different size)'},
    {key: 'leatherSeat', label: 'Seat Leather from Italy'},
  ]
}
```

I would need to process this data in order to get the key-values associated with my object key/// The tricky case i'm facing here, is in the case of the multiple choice.

Something like :

```
body: {
 carType: 'sport',
 carStyle: 'striped',
 carPrice: 'expensive',
 carOptions: ['aluminium', 'leatherSeat']
}
```

I did something quite verbose in ES5. I'd like, if possible, something cleaner to use with the ES6/ES7 feature to solve this.
Thanks for your time.

ps: Do not take in account the content of the data. It was made up for this topic. Only the data structure **cannot be modified** in my case.

Comment: I would like to know if I don't understand what the problem actually is because I'm still a little sick (it affects my head) or because it's really hard to understand?

Comment: Hi Morre. I just tried to provide some context. But you can just ignore it and try to find a way to pass from the first dataset to the second one :)

Comment: Ah, so you want to extract the keys. Well, `map` or `reduce` over the array of `Object.keys` and do the extraction in the callback function.... single key: obvious, array of objects: another `map` or `reduce` on the inner array.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a string to parse or a javascript object? this is not valid javascript syntax

Comment: My bad Axnyff. I did update my question

Comment: You should loop through the keys using Object.keys and create an object inside that loop

Comment: I want something short and cleaner than just nested loops. Using ES6/ES7 features i won't have thought about or don't know yet, for instance.

Comment: That's why I said `map`and/or `reduce`. The latter can be used to construct the result object right away, with an initial parameter of an empty object which you will fill in the `reduce` callback.

Comment: Fine Morre. Feel free to provide an example so i can close this topic ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you in ES6, using [Array.reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

```js
const data = {
  carType: {
    key: 'sport',
    label: 'Sports Car'
  },
  carStyle: {
    key: 'striped',
    label: 'Striped (with blabla)'
  },
  carPrice: {
    key: 'expensive',
    label: 'Above 500.000$'
  },
  carOptions: [{
      key: 'aluminium',
      label: 'Chrome Wheel (Available different size)'
    },
    {
      key: 'leatherSeat',
      label: 'Seat Leather from Italy'
    },
  ]
};

const changedData = Object.keys(data).reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x] = data[x] instanceof Array ? data[x].map(y => y.key) : data[x].key;

  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log(changedData);
```

Comment: There's no reason to assign `tmp` to `ptr`?

Comment: Just got same discussion elsewhere in SO :p It's all about the eslint [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) rule.

Comment: That's a horrible workaround. You rather should explicitly disable the rule for that function if you want to violate it.

Comment: This is not a workaround, look at second example in the eslint documentation. This is actually what they do. You can disable the rule if you want to.

Comment: Actually that seems better

Comment: @Bergi Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416399/create-a-string-using-foreach-in-javascript/47416471?noredirect=1#comment81788584_47416471) we had a discussion about it. Apparently there is disagreements in the github itself. I should disable the rules it seems.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT No, they don't? Assigning the parameter to a mutable variable only makes sense for primitive values, not for objects. You should disable the rule (in that line), use `{ "props": true }`, or `{ "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": ["tmp"] }`

Comment: @Bergi i've changed my eslint tho. Good thing to know. Learn things everyday. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no much you can do better in ES6 than in ES5:

```
const data = …;
const body = {};
for (const p in data)
    body[p] = Array.isArray(data[p])
      ? data[p].map(x => x.key)
      : data[p].key;
```

---

For comparison, using the most recent features (including experimental object spread syntax), you could do

```
const body = Object.entries(data).reduce((res, [p, val]) => ({
    ...res,
    [p]: Array.isArray(val)
       ? val.map(({key}) => key)
       : val.key
}), {});
```

Comment: And now add a `reduce` based version for the object so that he gets to see all the fancy ES6/7 stuff that is all the rage these days and that he seems to want to see :-)

Comment: You can use a ternary there. Thanks though

Comment: @Mörre No, I consciously decided against that - it's slower, less readable, and more complicated. You can post it in your own answer for comparison :-)

Comment: @LouisLecocq Ah, another line saved.

Comment: Alright. I hoped someone would come with the next syntax ES6/ES7. I guess not everyone's looking for it yet.
Will accept @Bergi. Thanks

Comment: @LouisLecocq I'm looking for it, I just don't think there's any advantage to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well with ES5 you can loop over the `data` object keys, and construct your new `body` object by testing over ech iterated `key`:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data[k])) {
    body[k] = data[k].key;
  } else {
    body[k] = data[k].map(function(opt) {
      return opt.key;
    });
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  carType: {
    key: 'sport',
    label: 'Sports Car'
  },
  carStyle: {
    key: 'striped',
    label: 'Striped (with blabla)'
  },
  carPrice: {
    key: 'expensive',
    label: 'Above 500.000$'
  },
  carOptions: [{
      key: 'aluminium',
      label: 'Chrome Wheel (Available different size)'
    },
    {
      key: 'leatherSeat',
      label: 'Seat Leather from Italy'
    },
  ]
};

var body = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data[k])) {
    body[k] = data[k].key;
  } else {
    body[k] = data[k].map(function(opt) {
      return opt.key;
    });
  }
});

console.log(body);
```

Comment: `carType` and `carStyle` should work the same as `carPrice`

Comment: @Bergi Yes it's in eS5, I wanted to show that it's almost the same thing, and I edited the logic, thank you.

Comment: I'd like it generic. How would that works with 10-20-50-100 more lines similar to carOptions.

Comment: @LouisLecocq You can use the `Array.isArray()` like in Bergi's answer to make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cleaner and readable functions and manipulation methods provided by `ES6`. Here is something `ES6` helps to solve your problem

```js
var data = {
  carType:  {key: 'sport',     label: 'Sports Car'},
  carStyle: {key: 'striped',   label: 'Striped (with blabla)'},
  carPrice: {key: 'expensive', label: 'Above 500.000$'},
  carOptions: [
    {key: 'aluminium',   label: 'Chrome Wheel (Available different size)'},
    {key: 'leatherSeat', label: 'Seat Leather from Italy'},
  ]
}
var obj = {};
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
  value: Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(a => a.key) : value.key,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
});
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: will work on IE > 9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: No it won't. Checkout Object.entries() Mozilla docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. Nice approach

Comment: Why do you use `Object.defineProperty` over a dead simple assignment?

Comment: just for fun ? or may be to play with `es6. #sorry

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lodash you can solution (1) in one line:

```
_.map(data, (element, index) => Array.isArray(element)?element.map(e=>e.key):element.key)
```

if you don't like ternary you can use solution (2) instead:

```
_.map(data, (element, index) => {
    if(Array.isArray(element)) {
        return element.map(e=>e.key)
    } else {
        return element.key
    }
})
```

and if you do not like lodash but you still want to use functional programing you can use solution (3):

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    if(Array.isArray(accumulator[key])) {
        accumulator[key] = data[key].map(e=>e.key)
    } else {
        accumulator[key] = data[key].key
    }
    return accumulator
},{})
```

My opinion is to use solution (1) or (2) using lodash because it has (almost) the same syntax as Array native methods.

Using ternary or not is up to you, as well as using conventional loops or not