# Create a string using forEach in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of strings like this:

`myData = ["111", "222", "333"]`

I want to build a string having this structure:

```
"{
 "111" : [{"type" : "line"}],
 "222" : [{"type" : "line"}],
 "333" : [{"type" : "line"}],
}"
```

Basically, for each element in array to add that type and line which are the same for all, and put it inside curly brackets, all this being a string.

This is my unsuccessful approach until now:

```
let result ="{";
myData.forEach(
    result = result + '"' + baselineTitle + '" [{"type":"line"}]'; 
);
result = result + "}"
```

Comment: Do you happen to want to create a JSON string…? Then create an object according to your desired format and `JSON.stringify` it.

Comment: Never create json manually. It is error prone and more work than creating objects/arrays and serializing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @deceze about using `JSON.stringify`, here is an example :

```js
const object = ['111', '222', '333'].reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x] = [{
    type: 'line',
  }];
  
  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));
```

---

You will notice the use of [Array.reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) which is the most adequate method to use in here.

---

**EDIT about ptr**

[image]

**EDIT 2 about ptr**

It's better to disable the [eslint no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) rule

Comment: Is there a need for the `ptr` variable?

Comment: It's a bad practice to modify a function parameter. At least in the style guide I use [airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--mutate-params). They say `Why? Reassigning parameters can lead to unexpected behavior, especially when accessing the arguments object. It can also cause optimization issues, especially in V8.`.

Comment: I would regard `ptr` as somewhat academic in this case. In general `no-param-reassign` is not wrong, but there's little technical reason to obey it here. It would make the code more concise to disregard it here. I don't think the engine optimisations which may or may not happen here make a big difference either way. At least you'd have to benchmark it.

Comment: I know you are not reassigning the pointer, but it still doesn't like it. Maybe about how V8 deal with the functions parameters. I'm not aware of how works V8 in details, so I trust professionals that tells me so :p

Comment: In this case the parameter still gets modified: https://jsfiddle.net/dopp4xfp/. looks like eslint is missing a `no-param-manipulation` rule.

Comment: @RolandStarke Correct - idk where we gotta report the behavior, maybe in eslint github?

Comment: @RolandStarke @deceze Interesting fact, in eslint [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) they have made the possibility to remove the parameter reassign error in case of Object manipulation `ignorePropertyModificationsFor`.

Comment: Looks like there is already a discussion on the usefullness: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5306

Comment: "I would never expect (nor have I ever seen) someone bypass this linter rule (`no-param-manipulation`) with your second example (reassigning the param variable)" :D

Comment: @RolandStarke ah ah

Comment: @RolandStarke I just disabled the rule in my eslint now. Learn things everyday :) Thanks gyu

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the object first and then get a stringified version of it.

```js
var array = ["111", "222", "333"],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: [{ type: "line" }] }))),
    json = JSON.stringify(object);

console.log(json);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you want to get JSON here.

I would use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead of generating it manually. Also I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method instead of `forEach`.

```js
const myData = ['111', '222', '333'];

const result = JSON.stringify(myData.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
    accumulator[currentValue] = [{type: 'line'}];
    return accumulator;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const result = ["111", "222", "333"].reduce((prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, {[curr]: [{type:'line'}]}), {});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to transform an array into an object like this:

```js
const data = ['111', '222', '333'];

const result = data.reduce((acc, value) => (
  {
    ...acc,
    [`${value}`]: [{type: 'line'}]
  }
), {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

And I decided to use pure stateless functional programming for the reduce case (without modifying any scope variable).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following snippet

```js
const myData = ["111", "222", "333"]
const result = {}
for( const item of myData) {
  result[item]=[];
  result[item].push({"type" : "line"});
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `result[item] = [{type: 'line'}];`…

Answer (score 0):

The forEach loop takes a function as argument, you did not specify arguments and the function itself, a solution would be like this :

```
let result ="{";
myData.forEach((baselineTitle) => {
    result = result + '"' + baselineTitle + '" [{"type":"line"}]'; 
});
result = result + "}"
```